# Unable to load environment variables from file over ssh

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, ssh

I running following command:

```
ssh -i ${SSH_KEY_PATH} ${SSH_SERVER_URI} "export $(grep -v '^#' /home/ubuntu/code/.env.prod | xargs -d '\n') && aws ecr get-login --region eu-central-1"
```

and getting following error:

```
Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".
```

Looks like env variables are not accessible. How to load then so that I can login to aws via AWS CLI?

Comment: When you put your string in double quotes, that makes the `$(...)` be executed _locally_, not on the remote host.

Comment: Also, you don't need a command substitution at all. `ssh ... 'set -a; . /home/ubuntu/code/.env.prod; set +a; aws ecr get-login --region eu-central-1` and you're done

Comment: BTW, all-caps variable names are used by the shell itself. Ideally, your own names would have at least one lower-case character to be in the namespace reserved for application use and guaranteed to not have unintended side effects on POSIX-compliant shells or other tools -- see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, keeping in mind that setting a shell variable overwrites any like-named environment variable (so the same naming conventions necessarily apply to both, at least within the namespace of shell names).

Comment: Also, note that `${var}` is no different from `$var` unless you need to parameterize the expansion or disambiguate trailing characters from part of the variable name, neither of which is the case here. If you want to add extra characters to make your script more correct, those characters should be _double quotes_, which instruct the shell to disable string-splitting and glob expansion (so `"$var"` or `"${var}"`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Why It Broke

When you put `$(...)` inside a double-quoted string, it's run while that string is being evaluated, which is **before** ssh starts. Consequently, the `grep` command runs on your local machine, which presumably doesn't have the file in question (or at least, doesn't have the same contents as the remote copy).

## How To Avoid The Problem

You don't need `$(...)` or `xargs` or `export` at all. Use `set -a` to make all variables be automatically exported, then source your file, with `set +a` used to turn auto-export back off when done:

```
ssh -i "$SSH_KEY_PATH" "$SSH_SERVER_URI" \
  'set -a; . /home/ubuntu/code/.env.prod; aws ecr get-login --region eu-central-1'
```